# Where to put non-SAML metadata like a country code inside the SP's metadata?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

I need to put some information inside the SP's metadata. The information is a country code and I think it is not defined in SAML or in one of it's extensions.

Where is the best place to put it? Is it better in IDPSSODescriptor, UIInfo-> Keywords or DiscoHints-> DomainHint?

Is there a similar example somewhere on the Internet?

I'm pretty new to SAML :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this myself by asking the saml-dev@lists.oasis-open.org mailing list.

```
  </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
  <md:Extensions>
      <mdattr:EntityAttributes>
          <md:Attribute Name="urn:countryCode" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
              <md:AttributeValue>IS</md:AttributeValue>
          </md:Attribute>
      </mdattr:EntityAttributes>
  </md:Extensions>
```